# Jsoup is not Correctly Working

Tags: java, jsoup

Hello guys i have an problem by Jsoup it is not working and i have no idea to figured it out here is the Code

```
    private void getWebsite() {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.jean-clermont-schule.de/seite/90384/vertretungsplan.html").get();
        Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("content");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is an [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lExGc.png)

Comment: Please do not ask us to look at pictures. Please tell us, in words, what you expect/want to happen and what actually happens. The picture is in any case redundant to the code you've supplied.

Comment: The odds of the problem being with JSoup itself and not with your code and your assumptions is astronomically small, not zero, but again extremely small. You will need to post a much more robust question complete with compilable [mcve] code and all error messages if you are going to convince us.

Comment: What error message do you get ? What did you try to solve it ? Like the others said, edit your question if you want SO members to help you.

Comment: its not working -.-

Comment: `"it's not working"` tells us absolutely nothing that helps us to understand your problem. Again, you're going to have to put in effort to ask a much more robust and answerable question. Up to you.

Comment: First thing to know is that a "wavey red line" is not "is not working", it means "Does not compile". Which means you've written something that doesn't conform to the rules of the language. You point your mouse at that part, and it will usually tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: It looks like you're using Intellij - amazingly your IDE is giving you more information about your error than you're giving us. Why don't you hover over the error and let us know what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code you provided is valid and compiles so the error is likely outside of what you've shown us. Looking at your picture, I guess you've imported the wrong Document class. Check your imports.

Comment: The code obviously *does not compile*. It may compile on your machine, but you're confusing the poor OP because his code doesn't compile as it's not the same as yours.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Agreed - hence my guess about the import. Have made a small update to the answer to be more specific

Comment: Thank you i import the wrong, but the app is keep crashing

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to add comment above.

I think that the code line `Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("content");` is wrong because `content` isn't tag for [this link](http://www.jean-clermont-schule.de/seite/90384/vertretungsplan.html).

You must provide `tag name` with `attribute` and `value` being optional while using `.select("");`

You may try `Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("div[id=content]");`